# What value will be set to the structure element command?

Tags: c, networking, operating-system

```
struct Descriptor *Rx_Descriptors = (struct Descriptor *)0x100000;
void setup_rx_descriptors()
 {
     unsigned int OWN = 0x80000000, EOR = 0x40000000; 
     int i;
     for(i = 0; i < num_of_rx_descriptors; i++) 
     {
         if(i == (num_of_rx_descriptors - 1)) 
           Rx_Descriptors[i].command = (OWN | EOR | (rx_buffer_len & 0x3FFF));
         else
           Rx_Descriptors[i].command = (OWN | (rx_buffer_len & 0x3FFF));

         Rx_Descriptors[i].low_buf = (unsigned int)&packet_buffer_address;
     }
 }
```

What happens to the command from Rx_Descriptors structure???

Comment: Right now, this question seems very vague.  Clarify.  What do you mean, "what happens to the command"?

Comment: I meant what happens to the statement `Rx_Descriptors[i].command = (OWN | EOR | (rx_buffer_len & 0x3FFF));`

Comment: Nothing "happens to" it.  It's right there.  It doesn't go anywhere.  Are you asking what the statement does as far as C is concerned?  Or what its visible effect in the OS is (which will vary across platforms)?  Or what's up with all the bit masking (which, again, will vary)?  If it's either of the two last ones, you'll need to include info about your OS and/or machine.

Comment: Yes I am asking what the statement does as far as C is concerned? Also about the bit masking? My OS is linux.

Answer (score 1):

For each Descriptor in the Rx_Descriptors array, command will be set to the low 14 bits of rx_buffer_len (presumably because 0x3fff (16383) is the maximum allowed and/or the other bits are used for something else).

The flag value OWN will be set for each of them, and EOR will be set for the last one only.